# How to allow users with Admin rights to access controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application in which I use Windows Authentication. Without getting too detailed my app sets up a series of users and gives then admin rights to create absences. If they have no admin rights then they can't change users or create absences.

I want to restrict access to certain controllers/actions based on the whether the admin flag in my database is set to true. The users where I work belong to multiple groups there is no administrator group which I can include in the Authorize attribute roles string.

I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/membership-and-administration) but as I have a database first entity framework model the entities class inherits from DbContext not from the identity context.

When I run the app my code raises an error saying: "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context." I click to view the details and I see this "The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context."

This is the code fragment of where the error occurs:

```
        AbsencesEntities context = new AbsencesEntities();

        AbsenceRepository absenceRepository = new AbsenceRepository(context);
        IdentityResult IdRoleResult;
        IdentityResult IdUserResult;

        // Create a RoleStore object by using the UserSecurity object.
        // The RoleStore is only allowed to contain IdentityRole objects.
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);

        // Create a RoleManager object that is only allowed to contain IdentityRole objects
        // When creating the RoleManager object, you pass in (as a parameter) a new RoleStore
        var roleMgr = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

        // Then, you create the "canEdit" role if it doesn't already exist
        if(!roleMgr.RoleExists("canEdit"))
        {
            IdRoleResult = roleMgr.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "canEdit" });
        }
```

Just to clarify I don't have any other context specified in the config file.

There must be a way for me to use Windows Authentication and use the LAN ID returned to check if it exists in the database. Then use that to check if the Admin flag is true in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inherit from authorizeattribute and override authorizecore, then just decorate your controller and/or methods with the attribute to handle this scenario. For instance:

```
public class PageAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (/*Rolemanager check*/) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            {"action", "PageDenied"}
            ,
            {"controller", "Authorization"}
        });
    }
}
```

You can use the `httpContext.User.Identity.Name` for checking the username.

```
[PageAuthorize]
public class PageController : Controller
{}
```

Comment: This is excellent - I tried it with one controller and it works fine. I click the link and it checks if the user is admin and lets me in or kicks me out. I would like to hide the links in my View to the controller based on the status of 'Admin' for the logged in user. I suspect that's a different question?

Comment: Yeah I would post that as a new question, it's a little out of scope for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Set Authorize attribute to whole controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
```

but to make it work you need to: 
Create custom principal and identity:

```
public class CustomIdentity : IIdentity
{
    private bool _IsAdmin;
    public bool IsAdmin
    {
        get { return _IsAdmin; }
    }

    // other properties
    public CustomIdentity(string Login)
    {
        using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
        {
        User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login.Equals(Login, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        _IsAdmin = user.IsAdmin;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    private CustomIdentity _Identity;
    public CustomPrincipal(string Login)
    {
        _Identity = new CustomIdentity(Login);
    }
    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        if (_Identity != null)
        {
            return role == "Administrator"? _Identity.IsAdmin: false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //other properties and code
}
```

In global.asax override PostAuthRequest:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        CustomPrincipal opPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal(User.Identity.Name);
        HttpContext.Current.User = opPrincipal;
    }
}
```

You should add column Login and same property to User table and class.